# ORA-00942 on connect through SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

The context:
I work with oracle 11.2.0.4 standard edition.
I create a new database (CREATE DATABASE + catalog + catproc)
I have a problem when I'm connect  on those database.
It works but I have a ORA-00942: table or view does not exist error!
Do you know this problem?

```
>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Tue Jan 20 16:22:27 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>  create user test PROFILE DEFAULT IDENTIFIED BY test  DEFAULT TABLESPACE TEST  TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP QUOTA UNLIMITED on test ACCOUNT UNLOCK;

User created.

SQL> grant connect to test;

Grant succeeded.
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production


>sqlplus test/test

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Tue Jan 20 16:13:50 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
```

Comment: Do you receive that error immediately as you login, or do you see if when you select into a table?

Comment: As you can see, it's direct on login. After, I can work..

Comment: Maybe your `login.sql` or `glogin.sql` that produces this. Do you also get this when you use a different SQL client?

Comment: There is no login script. I have the problem with this client for new db (olds work well). When I'm connecting thought another client, it's work well

Comment: Did you wind up solving this in the end??

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem at work recently - you log on to Oracle through sqlplus and on connecting it throws an ora-00942 (table or view does not exist).

It turns out the problem was we had not run `pupbld.sql` which is responsible for setting up a bunch of system tables that `sqlplus` (and **only** sqlplus) cares about. It's stuff to do with being able to assign different accounts different permissions when using sqlplus, hence on connect it tries to access those tables and if you haven't run `pupbld.sql` then it throws an ORA-00942 because the tables it expects to be there aren't there.

You should be able to solve the problem by running the following:
`sqlplus system/manager @?/sqlplus/admin/pupbld.sql`

NOTE: very important to run this as **system** as the tables are expected to exist in the system schema.